# Is it possible to autoupdate a chrome extension published outside the market?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that i built for my company employees,
we have our own instance of google apps @ourcompany.com

I have a gae app that tells the extension that it needs to be updated but the actual update process has to be done manually.

is there a way where i can do this update automatically once it's available?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you have control over the GAE app? What do you mean by "has to be done manually"?

Comment: yes i have my own gae application it has some info that is deliverd to my google extension

Comment: and i just notify the users that they have to go to a url and download the updated extension file and drag it to the extensions page to update the extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should publish your app to Chrome Web Store, and enjoy the auto-update process it offers, unless it's impossible due to CWS policies or packaging complications like Native Hosts/NPAPI.

When you do, you have an option to [restrict installs to users of your Google Apps domain](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2663860).

---

There are legitimate cases when you don't want to migrate over to CWS.

If you have a way to [force install of your extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions) (ideally via Group Policy) and not concerned by [tightening of security for Windows](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html), you can just use [update_url field](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate) in the manifest.

Comment: excellent i wanted something like update_url
is there a sample online for the server component that returns that response